# How does google indexing work?

Tags: joomla, sitemap, google-index

I have recently uploaded a joomla website in the web. I used the google webmasters and I uploaded the sitemap, which I made using the xmap component of joomla. This happened about 4 days ago, and now I get Submitted: 12 Indexed: 11 in the webmasters.

What I find out searching in google is that if I copy and paste the url of my website (or of a submenu item) it will be found. But using keywords, or even copying and pasting titles, does not find my website at all. I read about the google spiders that crawl in the web, but I am not sure I get it:

- Is it that it needs time to update the content of my website in google's database?
- Can I do something else in order to provide some keywords or content (I read somewhere about a "robots.txt file", but I think this provides a link to the sitemap once again)?

Any information on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: SEO is quite a big subject area, and certainly not one you'll get good answers to in this sort of forum. Suggest you search for suitable books - Google ranking, SEO might be some search terms to start with.

Comment: thank you for the comment and info. I will do some research on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a process for this and the bots have something to do with this.

hope this article helps you understand it further:

[Google indexing](http://www.googleguide.com/google_works.html),

[Read More](http://chillfire.blogspot.com/2009/10/google-indexing-and-how-i-think-it.html)

[image]

> Google doesn't guarantee that we'll crawl or index all of your URLs.
>   However, we use the data in your Sitemap to learn about your site's
>   structure, which will allow us to improve our crawler schedule and do
>   a better job crawling your site in the future. In most cases,
>   webmasters will benefit from Sitemap submission, and in no case will
>   you be penalized for it